# VIEW need to be for user specific

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using PLSQL, created a VIEW to get the details from a table and then use the VIEW to configure my report and display the details. But at one point of time, only one user details are updated in the VIEW.

If the first user generates the report at 10:00 AM and the second user generates the report at 10:01 AM, the details in the VIEW are from the second user. Can I make the VIEW to User/Session specific??

Comment: Views are just macros. They don't cache data or change behaviour by user or by whether they are executed recently. Your application should manage that

Answer (score 0):

That is not what views are for, the views just make it easy to combine tables and query it like it's a single table.
If you want to cache the results per user, you need to query the view and keep the cache your self per user, when you say the first user is generating the report at 10:00, cache the results and put it in the user session, so when that user comes back, he gets those same results, same for all other users

Answer (score 0):

Are you extracting data then insert it to a table? If so, you can create a GLOBAL TEMPORARY table and insert the data there instead. Data in global temporary table lasts only after session ended or after commit, it depends on how you create the table. Also, data in the table is per session.